# Stencil unable to test mouseenter\mouseleave events using Jest

Tags: jestjs, stenciljs

I built a simple button component using Stencil and assigned 4 events (`onMouseDown`, `onMouseUp` `onMouseEnter`, `onMouseLeave`),  to the button. The component looks like this:

```
   .
   .
   .
   @State() buttonState: string ='disabled';
   .
   .
   .
   someInternalLogic(eventName: Events) {
     ...//just sets a state variable of this.buttonState
   }
   render() {
     return (
       <button
         onMouseDown={() => this.someInternalLogic(Events.MOUSEDOWN)}
         onMouseUp={() => this.someInternalLogic(Events.MOUSEUP)}
         onMouseEnter={() => this.someInternalLogic(Events.MOUSEENTER)}
         onMouseLeave={() => this.someInternalLogic(Events.MOUSELEAVE)}
       >
       </button>
     );
   }
```

I'm new to testing in general and `Jest` in particular. I'm having troubles understanding how to test these events synthetically. I've come up with a workaround which works, but is obviously not the way to go.

The workaround:

```
  it('should mouseleave', async () => {
    const button = await page.root.shadowRoot.querySelector('button');
    
    const mouseleave = new window.Event("mouseleave", {
      bubbles: false,
      cancelable: false
    });

    let mouseleaveBool = false;
    button.addEventListener("mouseleave", e=>{
      mouseleaveBool = true;
    });
    await button.dispatchEvent(mouseleave);

    await page.waitForChanges();
    expect(mouseleaveBool ).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dispatching events you can directly call event handlers on your component instance

So for this component

```
export class TestBtn {
  onMouseLeave() {
    // do something
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Host>
        <button onMouseLeave={() => this.onMouseLeave()}>Test</button>
      </Host>
    );
  }
}
```

Test can look like this

```
describe('test-btn', () => {
  it('does something on mouse leave', async () => {
    // arrange
    const page = await newSpecPage({
      components: [TestBtn],
      html: `<test-btn></test-btn>`,
    });
    let component = page.rootInstance as TestBtn;

    // act
    component.onMouseLeave();

    // assert
    // check if did something
  });
});
```